# Completely remove View Controller - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I created a little game (not with Sprite Kit), I have a MenuViewController and a GameViewController.

On my GameViewController, I have a button "MENU" to go to the menu. I had this code to the GameViewController :

```
print("test")
```

It is executed every seconds with using a timer.

When I press the "MENU" button, I find myself on the menu but the timer is still running. I think the GameViewController is not completely removed, how can I do this ?

PS: to dismiss the GameViewController, I use this :

```
func goToMenuViewController() {

    let menuViewController = MenuViewController()
    menuViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    self.presentViewController(menuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**EDIT 1**

I add some infos about my app hierarchy :

When the user launch the app, he finds himself on the `MenuViewController`.
There is a play button on this ViewController which takes to the `GameViewController`.
On the `MenuViewController`, there is an other button which takes to the RulesEditorViewController, allowing to modify rules displayed on the `GameViewController`

Comment: you can stop the timer in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear method, and restart it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method based on your needs.

Comment: This is not the problem, I set up this timer to see if the GameViewController is completely removed.

Comment: According to code you provide the `GameViewController` will not be removed because it's still exists under your Menu view controller. And another thing why your `GameViewController` will not dealloc is a timer. You have to manually stop it to avoid memory allocations.

Comment: In fact, I use `NSUserDefault`, in the GameViewController, some rules are displayed, in an other ViewController, the user can edit these rules, and after editing a rule, I do this : `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(textFieldText, forKey: "textFieldText")` and after : `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`. When I return in the GameViewController, this is not the new rules but the old.

Comment: I don't see a link between your question and you comment. Please provide clear information about your view controllers hierarchy.

Comment: See my edit on the post

Answer (score 1):

Your try to dismiss `GameViewController` is wrong. You are create new `Menu` controller and showing it above the `GameViewController`. That's why this controller is still in app memory.

You have to use this function `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` or `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` depending on your segue type.

For now if you want access `RulesEditorViewController` you have to stop the game and leave this controller. But if you want modify options while playing then it will be better if you will access `RulesEditorViewController` directly from your `GameViewController` like you trying to show Menu now.

**Update:**
First of all you should understand view controllers hierarchy and ways how to present it. I believe this tutorial on example of storyboards will help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I used `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` but it does not work, when I edit the rules, there is still the old rules in the GameViewController :(

Comment: Is your `GameViewController` modal or embed in navigation controller?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand I'm new in iOS development, can you explain me what this means ? I don't use storyboards, only code.

Comment: How do you present your `GameViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

you can not see if the GameViewController is removed in this way. 
if you use a timer in a GameViewController, it will keep a ref to GameViewController until it stop executing.

By the way, present menu view controller won't make the game view controller be removed